# two way binding happening in react?

Tags: reactjs

i have heard that two way binding is not free in react. 
from this i understood that if we add an input field and type some text inside it shouldn't reflect pressed keys.
but with hooks(App1.js) or without hooks(App2.js) input field behaving the same, it reflects the typed text. can someone tell me the difference between the following codes( App1.js, App2.js).

```
index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='style.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="App1.js"></script>

    <div id="root2"></div>
    <script src="App2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

App1.js:
import React,{useState} from "react"
import {render} from "react-dom"
const App1 = ()=>{

    console.log("nnn")
    const [name,setName] = useState("hello")
    return (
    <div>
            <label htmlFor="name">
            </label>
            <input 
            id = "name"
            value = {name}
            onChange = {(e)=>(setName(e.target.value))}>
            </input>
    </div>
    )

}

render(<App1/>, document.getElementById("root"))

App2.js:
import React,{useState} from "react"
import {render} from "react-dom"
const App = ()=>{
    return (
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="name">
            </label>
            <input 
            id = "name">
            </input>
    </div>
    )
}

render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root2"))
```

why do we need hooks in this scenario ? when input in App2 is reflecting the typed text from keyboard.

i am new to react so kindly ignore my stupidity if i am being stupid.

Comment: How do you plan on accessing the value that the user typed in App2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 2-way data binding happening there. On your `App2.js` you are using an [Uncontrolled Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) which is not bound to React but to the normal DOM.